# Deserializing from MongoDB Enumerable as ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bson, tweetsharp

I have the following issue deserializing a TwitterStatus class in MongoDB, here is a failing unit test using the MongoDB C# driver 1.8.0.124 and TweetSharp 2.0:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
using System.Linq;
using TweetSharp;

namespace DS.Model.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestMongoSerialization
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CanDeserializeTwitterEntitiesFromMongoDB()
        {
            var server = new MongoClient().GetServer();
            MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("test");
            var tweets = db.GetCollection<TwitterStatus>("tweetSerialized");

            var tweet = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitterStatus>(tweetWithTwitterEntityiesSerialized);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, tweet.Entities.Count());
            Assert.AreEqual(TwitterEntityType.Url, tweet.Entities.First().EntityType);
            tweets.Save(tweet);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, tweets.FindAll().Count()); 

            var tweetFromMango = tweets.FindOne(Query<TwitterStatus>.EQ(s => s.Id, 315278676398858240));
            Assert.AreEqual(TwitterEntityType.Url, tweetFromMango.Entities.First().EntityType); // throws exception [1]
        }

        string tweetWithTwitterEntityiesSerialized = @"{""Id"":315278676398858240,""Text"":""TeePublic Funds 22 Designs "",""RetweetedStatus"":null,""created_at"":""2013-03-23T01:47:48Z"",""geo"":null,""Entities"":{""user_mentions"":[],""hashtags"":[],""urls"":[{""url"":""http://t.co/rBGN46rua7"",""expanded_url"":""http://zite.to/10uCED9"",""indices"":[71,93],""EntityType"":2}],""media"":[]},""possibly_sensitive"":false,""Place"":null}";

    }
}
```

The exception thrown is `Enumerable class TwitterEntities does not implement ICollection<T> so it can't be deserialized`, full stack trace below.

Full stack trace:

```
System.IO.FileFormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the Entities property of class TweetSharp.TwitterStatus: 
Enumerable class TwitterEntities does not implement ICollection<T> so it can't be deserialized. ---> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Enumerable class TwitterEntities does not implement ICollection<T> so it can't be deserialized.
Result StackTrace:  
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializer`1.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonReader bsonReader, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonReader bsonReader, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
```

How can I deserialize the TweetStatus class from mongoDB without this exception? 
For reference there are [the TwitterEntity classes](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/blob/master/src/TweetSharp/TwitterEntities.cs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TwitterStatus has a property

```
public virtual TwitterEntities Entities
```

and it is defined as

```
public class TwitterEntities : IEnumerable<TwitterEntity>
```

Now when deserializing JSon.NET makes an instance of **TwitterEntities** and after that tries to fill it with **TwitterEntity** items. But to do that it needs an Add method and **IEnumerable** doesn't provide one.
But [ICollection(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) does provide **Add** method and that's why it is asking for ICollection(T).

But if you are using MongoDb IMO you should not directly do any JSON conversion. You should have only simple POCO classes and MongoDb driver will take care of (de)serialization of these classes instances automagically for you.

That's the beauty of working with document database.

Comment: Thanks; I was hoping to use TwitterStatus as a simple POCO class for MongoDB, but I guess I need to map it to a simpler class of my own.